# What is causing to have the "load spike" issue on my server?

Tags: shared-hosting

I have list of websites (around 50 +)  on my nearer hosting provider hosting package. recently many of the sites being said the below **"note that your account has been suspended due to higher resource usage which causes load spikes in the server and lets the other sites gets down"**

All these sites build with Joomla and regular PHP coding. Not sure What I have to do as per the hosting side? any thoughts.,

Comment: Don't you have a set of administrator tools that allow you to figure out what these spikes are? Or at least you could contact your hosting provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your hosting provider, consult the problems with your current provider, or, if you have a lot of traffic comming to your site, change to better hosting solution